# PYTHON select lowest score in each group

Tags: python

I have the following in my database in an object called "item" and I want to write some python that will select the lowest score from each group of student_id....I am a total python noob...how would I do this?

```
{u'student_id': 197, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb88d'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 10.90872422518918}
{u'student_id': 197, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb88e'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 88.3871242475841}
{u'student_id': 198, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb892'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 17.46279901047208}
{u'student_id': 198, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb891'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 76.18366499496366}
{u'student_id': 199, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb895'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 49.34223066136407}
{u'student_id': 199, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb896'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 58.09608083191365}
```

UPDATE:

having some trouble running my code...can I get some sanity checking done? I'm getting this error...

```
NameError: name 'getResultFromDatabase' is not defined
```

Thank you for your trouble....here is my code...

```
import pymongo

from itertools import groupby
from pymongo import Connection

data = getResultFromDatabase()
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)

db = connection.students

item = db.grades.find({'type' : 'homework'}).sort([('student_id',pymongo.ASCENDING),('score',pymongo.ASCENDING)])



for id, items in groupby(data, lambda s: s['student_id']):
    lowest_score = min(i['score'] for i in items)

    print lowest_score
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = getResultFromDatabase()

for id, items in groupby(data, lambda s: s['student_id']):
    lowest_score_entry = min(items, key=lambda i: i['score'])
    print lowest_score_entry['score'], lowest_score_entry['_id']
```

Comment: +1.  The only thing the OP should watch out for when using `groupby` is that `data` has to be sorted by `student_id` (although if the example is representative, they might already be.)

Comment: noob report here. getting this error:      data = getResultFromDatabase()
NameError: name 'getResultFromDatabase' is not defined

Comment: I'm trying pip install itertools...ah heck...that didn't work

Comment: @Eric total noob here...how do I install itertools? Is that part of the regular python installation or do I need to install it some other way? (thank you for your time)

Comment: @thefonso: `itertools` is a default module, you don't need to install anything.  `getResultFromDatabase()` isn't an actual function -- Eric simply meant "do whatever you need to do to get `data` into a list (or other iterable) containing your dictionaries".

Comment: AHHH...as I said, nooooob. Thank you.

Comment: How would I grab the unique ObjectId for each min record found?