# Python - Group list and sort the lowest

Tags: python, list, sorting

Ive been thinking of how to sort list but by their group this might be similar to a post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316487/python-select-lowest-score-in-each-group) but mine is a bit different :

[image: The list]

I want the output to be something like this :
The output on the right,
data on the left
[image: Output]

the idea is i want to know the lowest match for image and put it inside a list then save it as CSV files.

Is there a Phytonic way of doing things like that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried list sort as `list.sort()`

Comment: Please add the content of the list in code. Also, you will have to explain your desired output, and what do you mean with "lowest match for image"?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath i tried but without the filename its just confusing, im so new to python so i cant quite grasp how to do it with the all

Answer (score 0):

So i found the keyword and working solution to that, mine was called nested list for anyone wonder how to solve this kind of problem try thi

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/